# Mint NFT to specific OpenSea collection

Tags: nft, opensea

I am following this tutorial for Moralis https://moralis.io/how-to-create-your-own-nft-in-5-steps/ to create a NFT on OpenSea.

I have a collection on OpenSea that I want the NFT's to be added to. Is it possible to specify which collection the NFT should belong to when minting the token?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: Not yet, it's possible that you have to use your own smart contract to connect to specific collection.

Comment: Any tutorial or article for that? "use your own smart contract to connect to specific collection"

Comment: It's possible that Moralis doesn't expose all the functionality from OpenSea. So maybe it's possible to do this from their SDK https://projectopensea.github.io/opensea-js/. You could also checkout rarible.com and use their web UI to create and link your own smart contract to a collection. https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155